# Codeigniter/Postgresql: Site works but cannot fetch data from db

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter

I am using Postgresql database connection with codeigniter. I am new to postgresql. The site opens. But I cannot login nor fetch any values from the database.

I will upload the code for my config file as well as the database.php file.
**config.php**

```
// Keep as it is for same if MySQL server is running on same server
define("DBHOSTNAME",'ip_address');

// Add your database name here
define("DBNAME",'db_name'); // Here the database name is 'dummy_myecommerce'

// Add your database user name here
define("DBUSER",'username');  // Here the username is 'dummy_website'

// Add your database password here
define("DBPWD",'password');
```

Now I will upload the **database.php** file:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'ip_address';
$db['default']['username'] = 'username';
$db['default']['password'] = 'password';
$db['default']['database'] = 'db_name';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'postgre';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = 'pre_';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['port'] = 5432;
```

If anything else is required, please let me know. Thanks

Comment: look in your application/config directory for a file called autoload.php do you've autoloaded your DB Library ?

$autoload['libraries'] = array("database",....);

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Some database drivers (such as PDO, PostgreSQL, Oracle, ODBC) might require a full DSN string to be provided. If that is the case, you should use the ‘dsn’ configuration setting, as if you’re using the driver’s underlying native PHP extension, like this:

// PDO
$db['default']['dsn'] = 'pgsql:host=localhost;port=5432;dbname=database_name';

Helpful link - http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/configuration.html

Comment: first try with a local script to connect to postgre, to make sure details are correct

Comment: local script using corephp from this link http://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_php.htm seemed to work

Comment: try $db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'pdo'; //set driver here. Check my other answer above.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay, I managed to fix it, there was an issue in the DB

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this as well

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=yourdb'; //set host
$db['default']['username'] = 'your username'; //set username
$db['default']['password'] = 'your password'; //set password
$db['default']['database'] = 'your database'; //set databse
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'pdo'; //set driver here
```